# Keeping an HTTPClientConnection open within a class object

Tags: java, apache, http-headers, httprequest, httpclient

Im using a DefaultHttpClientConnection to send http post requests. Is it possible to reuse the http connection? For example, instantiate and set up the connection and bind a socket to it, and then assign it to a static field in the class. Then for every function call to send an http post, I would just reuse the same DefaultHttpClientConnection that I set up earlier. I've tried to reuse it that way, but I keep getting an HTTPException saying I have invalid protocols. The code works if I instantiate a new DefaultHttpClientConnection and set it up every time I send a post, but I get that exception whenever I try to be efficient and reuse it.

This is in Java.

```
  /*
   * These settings shall speed up the sending of the http request...
   * */
  BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
  //Use HTTP 1.1 so we open a TCP connection per request sent
  params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
  //Turn off Nagle's Algorithm to speed things up
  HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(params, true);
  params.setBooleanParameter(HttpProtocolParams.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
  params.setBooleanParameter(HttpConnectionParams.STALE_CONNECTION_CHECK, false);
  params.setIntParameter(HttpConnectionParams.SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE, 8 * 1024);
  client.setParams(params);
  DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy connStrategy = new DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy();

  HttpResponse resp = null;
  if (conn == null)
  {
    executor = new HttpRequestExecutor();
    context = new BasicHttpContext();
    httpproc = new BasicHttpProcessor();
    /*Set http connection processors, mostly default settings
     * What these protocols do, can be easily found online ;) */
    httpproc.addInterceptor(new RequestContent());
    httpproc.addInterceptor(new RequestTargetHost());
    // Recommended protocol interceptors
    httpproc.addInterceptor(new RequestConnControl());
    httpproc.addInterceptor(new RequestUserAgent());
    httpproc.addInterceptor(new RequestExpectContinue());
  }

  conn = new DefaultHttpClientConnection();
  if (!conn.isOpen())
  {
    //Opening the socket
    try
    {
      socket = new Socket(request.getURI().getHost(), request.getURI().getPort());
      try
      {
        //Bind socket to the connection
        TTLog.log("connection binding to socket...");
        conn.bind(socket, client.getParams());
      }
      catch (IOException e1)
      {
        TTLog.log("Failed to bind the socket to the HTTPConnection...");
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e1)
    {
      TTLog.log("The host name is invalid... Hostname: " + request.getURI().getHost());
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e1)
    {
      TTLog.log("I/O Error when creating socket...");
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Here's the exception:

> org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Not a valid protocol version: ??)»L
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:181)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:185)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:284)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:126)

Comment: This code is how I have the set up of the connection done currently. I create a new DefaultHttpClientConnection every time the method gets invoked. Trying to avoid that and keep that DefaultHttpClientConnection on a static variable in the class.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the question with the exception I get when I try to reuse.

Comment: Exception happens when I do executor.execute.

Comment: 1. Delete your obsolete comments after you edit the question. 2. Your code is incomplete: post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve including any import statements so that we don't have to guess which classes you use. Your code also does not show how often you call it and what may happen in between calls. 3. You create that executor, but never do anything with it --- post your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a stateless and connectionless protocol. That means server and client just meets on current request and afterwards session disposes and they forget about each other. If you want to keep the connection session, you gonna need to use Websockets.

Comment: Ah... I see I see. Thanks!

Comment: You r welcome! You can do further read from the link. Good luck! https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_overview.htm